# Javascript/HTML show alert before value changed on browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple counter webpage which has a "+1" button and a count display. When you click the button, the counts on the webpage increases by 1. When the counts reach 5, the page is supposed to pop up an alert and reset the counter to 0.

However, when the counter reaches 5, the webpage still shows "Counts:4" and the alert shows up. What's more, the tag's innerText has already become "Counts:5". So why is there an inconsistence between the HTML and the actual webpage? Does it have anything to do with asynchronous operations?

[image]
I could add a `setTimeout(function(){alert("Counter value: "+ totalCount)},1000);` to delay the alert. But that's not my original intention. The alert should always pop up right after the counter hits 5 and displays as "Counts:5".

```js
let totalCount = 0;

function onload() {
  document.getElementById("increment").addEventListener("click", onClick);
  renderCounter();
}

function onClick() {
  totalCount++;
  renderCounter();

  if (totalCount > 4) {
    alert("Counter value: " + totalCount);
    totalCount = 0;
    renderCounter();
  }
}

function renderCounter() {
  let counts = document.getElementById("counter");
  counts.innerText = "Counts: " + totalCount;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onload()">
  <header id="header">
    <h1>Interesting tests</h1>
  </header>
  <section class="my-counter">
    <p id="counter"></p>
  </section>

  <section id="increment-button">
    <button type="button" id="increment"> +1 </button>
  </section>

  <script src="increment.js"></script>
```

Comment: You reset `totalCount` before you render it with `renderCounter()`. Simply removing `renderCounter()` in the conditional block should fix it.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Because the renderCounter() is always called in the onClick() function. It's supposed to display a 0 if totalCount > 4.
Edit: to clarify, that renderCounter() after resetting totalCount is on purpose. It'll make the webpage to display "Counts:0".

Answer (score 1):

You DO need the setTimeout, but it does not have to be 1 sec

1. Don't reset before rendering
2. alert is blocking so the interface does not get a chance to update
3. Allow the rendering, then alert, then render again
4. Use eventListener instead of inline event handlers

```js
let totalCount = 0;

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("increment").addEventListener("click", onClick);
  renderCounter();
})

function onClick() {
  totalCount++;
  renderCounter();
  if (totalCount > 4) {
    totalCount = 0;
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert("Counter value: " + totalCount);
      renderCounter();
    }, 10); // allow the interface to update
  }
}

function renderCounter() {
  let counts = document.getElementById("counter");
  counts.innerText = "Counts: " + totalCount;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <h1>Interesting tests</h1>
</header>
<section class="my-counter">
  <p id="counter"></p>
</section>

<section id="increment-button">
  <button type="button" id="increment"> +1 </button>
</section>

<script src="increment.js"></script>
```